# Is it best practice to use update_attribute action in Rails CRUD Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can use it but I am sure if it is a good practice to use update_attribute action in Show action in Rails. If its a bad practice please suggest for the best alternatives since I need to update a column of row on every show action.

My code

```
def show
        @package = Package.friendly.find(params[:id])
        @pack = Package.where(:category_id => @package.category_id).sample(4)
        @setting = Setting.find(1)
        counter = @package.counter
        count = counter+1
        @package.update_attributes(:counter => count)
    end
```

Comment: well, show action ("read" in CRUD) is not supposed to change data. But you gotta do it, you gotta do it.

Comment: yes it is not supposed to change data but however we can write some action. Thanks, I shall Implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails CRUD convention "show" should route from an HTTP GET. In general, it's best to avoid modifying any state of the database from a GET action. So, to answer your question, no, it's not a best practice to use `update_attribute` in a show action.

Comment: So is there any other best practice. I have updated my question with the program code. Please suggest me the best alternative!

Answer (score 0):

This is really a odd processing to obtain a count and then increment it by values then update it to table

It's make slower into that

For Best Practices You can implement like this

```
 item = Item.find(1)
 item.foo_count # => 0
 Item.increment_counter(:foo_count, 1)
 item.foo_count # => 0
 item.reload
 item.foo_count # => 1
 item.increment(:foo_count)
 item.foo_count # => 2
```

As per your logic the code will be

```
 Package.increment_counter(:counter, 1)
 @package.increment(:counter)
```